# Firestore security rules, how to check if claim exists and is a string

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am storing game character username in a custom claim, this is done to avoid several get requests on database to get username and proceed with other actions. I want to define a security rule that only allows users with usernames to access certain data. Ideally I'd check to see if token claim is a string and has length. But so far best I came up with was to check if this token claim is defined or not via:

```
request.auth.token.username != null
```

Is it possible, to check for type (string) and length here as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.auth.token` is a map of JWT token claims (see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request?authuser=0#auth)). So you can use the [`Map`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map?authuser=0) properties and methods to check the type.

To get the string length, use the [`size`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String?authuser=0#size) property of `String`.