# How to authenticate Firestore using signInWithCustomToken() (Nodejs firebase token)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have these Firestore rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isValidUser(userId) {
      return request.auth.uid == userId && request.auth.role == 'user';
    }
    function isLoggedIn() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    match /users/{id}/{document=**}{
      allow create, read, update, delete: if isLoggedIn() && isValidUser(id)
    }
  }
}
```

And I create a valid Firebase token via a Google cloud function and send it to whoever logs in successfully, like this

```
const firebaseToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uuid);
return res.status(200).json({status: true, token: firebaseToken, id: uuid});
```

Now we go to Flutter, in `main.dart`

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (Firebase.apps.isEmpty) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  }
  Instance.registerTypes(onRegister: (getIt) {
    getIt.registerLazySingleton(() => BusinessDevice());
  });

  runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: ProviderScope(
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

And in `login.dart`

```
final headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
final request = http.Request(
'POST', Uri.parse(ENDPOINTS.FIREBASE_AUTH));
request.body = json.encode({
"email": userCtrl.text.trim(),
"password": passCtrl.text.trim(),
"role": "user"
});
request.headers.addAll(headers);
http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
final body = await response.stream.bytesToString();
final jsonResponse = json.decode(body);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
// Authentication succeeded, store the token and navigate to the dashboard
final token = jsonResponse['token'];
final userid = jsonResponse['id'];
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCustomToken(token);
 DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users').doc(userid).get();
}
```

I'm getting this error when the application tries to read from Firestore

`FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)`

We're using `signInWithCustomToken()`, because we have a username and password authentication system, which isn't supported out of the box by Firebase so I had to write a Google cloud function to handle this.

I'm looking for a solution that will require the fewest changes in the codebase. Because we are facing the same issue in 3 different big apps in production and Firestore is used on all the pages. I want to work on securing the apps and not refactoring them.

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.

Comment: @anothermh Good point, but my question is about flutter, if I remove flutter, then nodejs and google cloud expert will read this question, and waste their time. Flutter experts might not even notice it since it has nodejs in the title - and because they might not check the tags. I've been using SO for very long time and tried many types, adding tags in the title is very effective

Comment: Apparently you didn't read my comment or the linked article. Don't force tags into the title.

Comment: It helps to first figure which exact part of your code isn't working. For example, of you temporarily comment out this part of the check `request.auth.role == 'user'`, does it then work? If so, it sounds like the role is missing from the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `role` is a custom claim, in which case it exists in the `token` property in your rules. So:

```
return request.auth.uid == userId && request.auth.token.role == 'user'
                                              //
```

Also see:

- [Firestore security rules, how to check if claim exists and is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65978815/209103)
- The documentation on [`request.auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request)

Comment: Man you're a legend, i can't remember how many times you helped me, and to go on a hunch like that super impressive, man I love it, that's just legendary, forever grateful man.